# Writing an operator as $ \hat{A} $ = $\sum_{n=1}^{2} a_n|a_n\rangle\langle a_n|.$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We have the operator

\begin{equation} 
A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I found its eigenvalue which is $\lambda$ = 0.

Now the question is whether the operator can be written as $ \hat{A} $ = $\sum_{n=1}^{2} a_n|a_n\rangle\langle a_n|$ ?

I think it can not be written in that form because the eigenvalue is zero.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean both eigenvalues are $0$ or *one* if them is $0$?  It’s a $2\times 2$ matrix so it should have $2$ eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't be written this way:

- The operator is not Hermitian, so its right and left eigenvectors are not simply hermitian conjugates of each other.
- The eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ is degenerate.

Comment: Right but imagine the diagonal matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$.  It is hermitian, and $\lambda=0$ is not degenerate.

Comment: For a Hermitian matrix it can be done. For a non-Hermitian there is a more general expansion in terms of the left- and right- eigenvectors

Comment: Yes I understood the question as one where the focus was on a matrix with a $0$ eigenvalue.

Comment: I edited the previous comment: the problem is that the expansion cited is specific to Hermitian matrices... although, I suppose, it depends on how one defines bras and kets.